# video card debugging tool

Tags: drivers, graphics-card

Are there any good tools for debugging video cards to determine if its a hardware or driver issue?

My system recently started to hang during some games (not all games), causing me to do a hard reboot as it stops responding and no blue screen comes up.

I've tried reinstalling drivers (both new and old), measuring temperature, voltage, everything checks out normal, but this issue still happens.

So is there anything out there that can help me isolate the problem?

Answer (score 1):

For a start you could e.g. try [MemtestG80: A Memory and Logic Tester for NVIDIA CUDA-enabled GPUs](https://simtk.org/home/memtest/) or [CUDA GPU memtest](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cudagpumemtest/) to make sure your GPU has no memory errors.

While you're at it you maybe should also check your RAM with [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) because main memory errors could be the cause of your problems, too. Run it over night (i.e. several passes).